# how do i run (configure to run) .r file in intellij idea?

Tags: r, intellij-idea

i've tried to use r plugin in idea. everything seems to be fine, but
there seems to be no R run configuration option in Intellij Idea 14.
just can't configure it - there seems to be no R option.
How do i run .r file in idea?

Comment: Have you seen - https://github.com/holgerbrandl/r4intellij

Comment: for shure  **i did see it**, the plugin i've mentioned was r4intellij, _there's no other known to me r plugin_. The problem is **there weren't suitable for .r run configuration ability**

Comment: using it for a while, not-so-idea-ide-lish way of operaton. my hope is the plugin finally will become full-blown

Answer (score 1):

With the more recent versions of the "R language support" plugin, you can simply create regular run configurations to run your scripts:
[image]

Also there is an integrated console now, to interactively run your scripts.